Connecting Two 24VDC Power Supplies
I have a system that has multiple different gas detection sensors and we are datalogging our readings onto a PLC. To power our sensors we are using a 10 A power supply and have everything grounded together including the PLC datalogging channels all share the same GND as the power supply as this is standard. However our O2 sensors will draw current that exceeds the power supply limit on start-up when in operation it will be within range (the probe has to heat to 300°C).
To tackle this issue we are going to introduce a second power supply and have it power the O2 sensors only. Now to make this safe and work. will I have to GND both power supplies together or can I just add the second power supply and connect it to the O2 sensor as its own separate circuit and go to all the PLC ports the O2 sensor was connected to and swap the grounds out for the new power supply?
Thank you

There's no problem with this, just ensure that you have an idea of ground paths. Ideally go with a "star ground" as in tie the grounds together at the point where they leave your device.

Having multiple supplies is possible, as long as you ensure common ground and avoid any cross-feed between the Supplies.
Different question: Why not use a stronger supply to feed the whole circuit in the first place?
That way you avoid the dual supply and any grounding headache.

It is better for you to connect both GND and make one reference GND. So you can avoid any noise in data logging part.
